# hubot coffee script - how to set and get brain into file

Tags: coffeescript, hubot

How do I save the robot brain into a file and load brain data from the file again?

I need it to keep brain persistence in case hubot crashes and want to use his last thoughts when getting it up again.

Comment: have you thought about using the redis brain? pretty sure it ships with hubot by default. just need a redis server on localhost or configure it to use a remote redis: https://github.com/hubot-scripts/hubot-redis-brain

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem but this worked for me. In order to start redis-brain, you will have to install redis from your browser(same for Windows,Linux, etc,.). After downloading, go to command prompt and open it as an "Admin". In cmd go to Program Files and open Redis and run this "redis-server.exe". Now you have completed setup redis-brain for your project. Hope this would help you!